# drupal 6 NOT showing php notices

Tags: 6

I am trying to make php show error notices, but it doesn't work. For my error settings I have write errors to screen and log.

I tried this: (in page.tpl.php)

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
$abc = array();
echo $abc['test'];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable error messages, add the following to your *index.php*:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

Comment: settings.php is a better place so it gets preserved across updates; editing core files isn't the best idea.

Answer (score 2):

Answer is already accepted, but editing index.php isn't the greatest idea.  It is a core file and will get replaced when you apply an update.

There are two ways you can go about this.

One is to put the code in settings.php, along with the other php variable overrides.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", TRUE);
ini_set("display_startup_errors", TRUE);
```

The other way (assuming Apache) is to put the statements in your .htaccess or your Apache config for the host.  .htaccess may get replaced when you update, so Apache config is the better option here.  The only thing to be aware of is that E_ALL is a constant in PHP, and you have to use the numeric value.

When I execute

```
<?php print E_ALL; ?>
```

I get the value 30719.  You can then use

```
php_value error_reporting 30719
php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
```

Note that the value of E_ALL may be different on your machine, depending on the version of PHP you are using and vanilla Apache/PHP vs Zend Server.

Then restart Apache.  You can verify these by making a file with

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

in your DOCROOT and browsing to it and viewing the settings section.  Remember to remove it when you go live, or lock it down by IP or password.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [article](http://drupal.org/node/158043) for the code to add to your index.php.

Answer (score 0):

I have an article on this subject: http://groups.drupal.org/node/170339